# Cuccumber + Capybara, When running a scenario in my feature file only the background steps are running whilst the scenario steps are ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

After quite a few hours of searching for answers to this to no avail, along with trying to source the issue myself within rubymine, I am now resigning to asking a question for it...

When I run one of my scenario's in my feature file, or all scenario's, it only processes the background steps and then ignores all the others that are within my scenario.

The stats at the end then report:

1 Scenario (1 Failed)
4 Steps (3 Skipped, 1 Passed)

So no steps failed! I have verified that the scenario works on another machine and passes successfully. Does anyone have an idea why it would just be ignoring my scenario steps?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually managed to fix this problem myself!!! :)

In the javascript_emulation.rb file there is a known issue around capybara and racktest, the workaround and easy fix for that is to remove ::Driver after :Capybara for the java emulation bits.

If none of the ::Driver entries are removed the following error is returned:

undefined method 'click' for class 'Capybara::Driver:RackTest:Node' (NameError)

then a list of the problem areas in different files.

If the ::Driver entry is removed from the class Capybara::Driver:RackTest::Node 
then the test will run but only process the background tests.

All instances of ::Driver must be removed in this file. For me there were 4 in total.

Hope this helps others :)